# Types for Array Destructuring

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm mapping through an array and using destructuring.

```js
const newArr = arr.map(({name, age}) => `${name} ${age}`)
```

The above errors as: ***Binding element 'name' implicitly has an 'any' type***

Error goes away by adding:

```
const newArr = arr.map(({name, age}: { name: string; age: number }) => `${name} ${age}`)
```

**The question is:** Could I go about this with a more terse syntax and/or apply the needed types via an interface?

---

**UPDATE:** As a combination from the comments below and the suggestions by @grumbler_chester and @TimWickstrom

This was the more terse way I found to shorten my syntax:

*Solution:*

```js
// User.tsx
interface User {
  name: string 
  age: number
}

const newArr = arr.map(({name, age}: User) => `${name} ${age}`)
```

Comment: Relevant github issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7576

Comment: Is `arr` variable typified?

Comment: @grumbler_chester How so?

Comment: @Jonca33 Does it have some type annotation like:
    type User {
        name: string;
        age: number;
    }
    const arr: User[] = ...

Comment: @grumbler_chester I didn't add any types to `arr`. Suggestions?

Comment: @Jonca33 I suppose TS can infer type of destructed fields if array for mapping (`arr`) is typified.

Comment: @grumbler_chester cld you pls post an answer with what you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to maintain strict type checking you could define your models.

File Architecture example.

```
/src
  /models
    Person.js
```

Person.js

```
export default {
  name: string,
  age: number
}
```

In your file

Import Person from './models/Person.js' // Path to Person.js

```
const newArr = arr.map(({name, age}:Person) => `${name} ${age}`)
```

Alternatively, if you do not require strict type checking and would like to suppress the warning this should work:

In your tsconfig.json (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) you can add the following:

from

```
"noImplicitAny": false,
```

to

```
"noImplicitAny": true,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add type annotation to your `arr` variable and TS will infer type of destructed fields.

Please see [example in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Person%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20arr0%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0Aconst%20arr1%3A%20Person%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20newArr0%20%3D%20arr0.map((%7B%20name%2C%20age%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%60%24%7Bname%7D%20%24%7Bage%7D%60)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20newArr1%20%3D%20arr1.map((%7B%20name%2C%20age%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%60%24%7Bname%7D%20%24%7Bage%7D%60)%3B) (note `noImplicitAny` is `true` in options, error for `arr0` mapping and no error for `arr1` mapping)

And please check [Type Inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) for theory behind example.

Comment: @Jonca33 I cannot provide you exact answer without the code but in general usual reason for such error is a collision when TS loses/cannot infer type of `arr` somewhere "above".

Comment: indeed, I appreciate your insight, that lead me to a solution, please see my updated question.